# When I use TCP to send data how do I know if data has arrived or not?

Tags: linux, tcp

When i use TCP to send data, the `write()` function just ensures data has been copied to the TCP send buffer, but if TCP doesn't send data successfully, how do I know? Is there a signal? or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**: you don't. Conventionally the remote TCP peer sends a response, acknowledging your data. This is the 1st step toward building an application level protocol, atop TCP, your transport level protocol.

**Longer Answer**: This problem is the prime motivation for higher level protocols such as HTTP, STOMP, IMAP, etc.

> but if TCP doesn't send data successfully, how do I know?

The `write()` system call can return `-1` and set `errno` to indicate an error, however you cannot know how much data has been received by the remote peer, and how much was not. That question is best answered by the remote peer.

M.

Comment: So if i write() data into send buffer,and the data doesn't arrived the remote peer,i will not know this event,unless i ask the remote peer sends a response to me ?

Comment: Essentially, yes. As you intimate a call to `write()` means the bytes have made it to the local socket buffer, and possibly no further.

Comment: A pleasure. Can you assign some more tags to your question to clarify which platform you're using? I assume POSIX/UNIX/Linux .. but I may be mistaken.